# Call future method in a catch and before a new exception is thrown

Tags: apex

I need to execute a future method (with callout) when an exception is caught, at the same time, just after that, I need to thrown another custom exception. It seems both things can not play together...following some pieces of code to clarify the behavior

```
    try {
        uow.commitWork();
    }catch (DmlException e){
        deleteAppoitment(calendarProviderEventId, requestDTO.selectedAgentId);
        throw new AppointmentException('My custom error message');
    }
```

Where:

```
@Future(Callout=true)
private static void deleteAppoitment(String calendarProviderEventId, String userId) {
    //Do Something
}
```

Is there any option to do it? or the only thing I can do is returning null instead of the throwing the custom exception...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throwing an uncaught exception fully reverts the state of the database, including future methods, sending emails, schedulable, queueable, etc. The only exception to this is the [EventBus.publish](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_eventbus.htm) method, when the Platform Event is set to "Deliver Immediately." This is the only mechanism you can use to perform additional asynchronous work *and* throw an uncaught exception.

```
try {
    uow.commitWork();
}catch (DmlException e){
    DeleteEvent__e deleteEvent = new DeleteEvent__c(ProviderEventId__c=calendarProviderEventId, SelectedAgentId__c=requestDTO.selectedAgentId);
    EventBus.publish(deleteEvent);
    throw new AppointmentException('My custom error message');
}
```

From there, you can define a trigger to do additional logic:

```
trigger DeleteEventHandler on DeleteEvent__e(after insert) {
  // Perform your desired logic here
}
```

These triggers don't count against daily Platform Event limits.

You can read more about [Platform Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro.htm) in the docs.

Comment: Amazing! Working perfectly! Good to know!